# Will browsers cache pages with a different ETag?

Tags: html, http, caching, nginx, http-headers

I don't know much about how caching works, or much control over my hosting's nginx server. However, I do have a live site that I need to make a change to, so your advice will be very much appreciated.

Currently I have the following three files:

```
index.html
my.js
my.css
```

All the files are being served (on my browser) with the following headers:

```
Date:Wed, 22 Feb 2012 23:17:49 GMT
ETag:"b2c84d1-7551-4b995b0c89c0"
Last-Modified:Wed, 22 Feb 2012 23:14:34 GMT
Server:nginx
```

There aren't any other cache-related headers. Given the above, if I simply replace the files with new versions, can I assume that users' browsers will know not to use cached versions? (I assume if I replace the file, the ETag will change.)

What I'd like to avoid is a situation where a user's browser downloads the new version of `index.html` but continues to refer to a cached version of `my.js`, because that's likely to break things. I'd also like to know if I can rely on the users seeing the newer version of the site, or if some users will continue to see a cached version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will send the `If-Modified-Since:` and (if you have a recent browser) the `If-None-Match:` headers, the first refering to the `Last-Modified:` header, the latter containing the `ETag`. The server will send the new file, if the modification date is newer than the Last-Modified header. How the ETag changes will depend on your server, but in most cases this will be a hash over the file content.

So just make sure that both the file content changes and the modification date is up-to-date (e.g. by `touch /var/www/your-file.js`).

Comment: Thanks! I don't see my browser (Chrome) sending either of the If-* headers you mention, at least not I can't see them attached to the request when I look in Developer Tools. But I'll take your word for it that changing the content, and touching the file, will mean no caching. Thank you for your help.